# PHP timezone error while using errors logger

Tags: php, timezone, error-logging

Code to reproduce:

```
error_reporting(-1);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'log/log');        
ini_set('html_errors', 0);

// trigger an error
echo $test;
```

If `log/log` is writeable and you didn't set `date.timezone` in `php.ini` or used [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set), you will see this error:

> Warning: main(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Paris' for
>   '1.0/no DST' instead in C:\srv\www\test.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: test in C:\srv\www\test.php on line 10

Which is extremely informative. 10 line in my case is `echo $test;`. PHP doesn't tells anything about line with setting the error logger.

You can spend a lot of time on large project pointing this out.

If `log/log` isn't writeable, you will see only undefined variable notice.

I think that PHP could use system timezone settings for logs (which would be kinda obvious).

Is ist a bug and should it be reported to PHP team? Btw. I use PHP 5.3.8 (not last snapshot)

Comment: In your "Code to reproduce" $test is never set.  Copy & Paste error?

Comment: It is made to trigger an error, so php will try to log it.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  To clarify, what is your question here?  It looks like a bug report.

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your log it is writable, the notice will trigger a log line that contains a formatted timestamp. This timestamp is displayed in your servers timezone.

Now take a look at the WARNING (it is no error). It is telling "We selected 'Europe/Paris' for '1.0/no DST' instead". PHP read the configured server timezone (from /etc/timezone?) and got "1.0/no DST". That is no usable timezone information (for php). Instead it is using "Europe/Paris" as fallback.

If the log file is not writable, no warning is raised because no formatted time string is generated.

I don't know if "1.0/no DST" is a valid timezone format, but I would not change anything in your /etc/timezone.

So please don't submit a bug ;)

Comment: Seems to be a common problem... Just googled for "1.0 no DST" and found tons of pages that produces this warning.